# Applying a while loop over a list when typeof is TRUE

Tags: r, while-loop

I am trying to correctly apply a `TRUE` while loop over a list of data. I ultimately want to execute a function if the list contains a `character` error. For example, if I have something that looks like:

```
List of 6
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ c..A....B....C..: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ : chr "Error"
 $ : chr "Error"
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ c..A....B....C..: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ c..A....B....C..: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ : chr "Error"
```

I want to apply a function, (or here print) when it sees the `character` list of `Error` lists. Ignoring the `list` part.

Once the `character` lists have been processed they will then also change to `data.frame` objects and no longer be `character` objects. I want the `while` loop to keep iterating through the lists until all lists have been changed from `character` to `data.frame` lists - i.e. when `while(FALSE)` occurs.

Question:

How can I iterate through a list applying a function to each element if it contains `character`, move onto the next, "skip" if it is a `data.frame`, move onto the next etc. Once the list is complete, re-do the whole process again, find the next `character` (skipping `data.frames`), and keep doing this until all list elements are `data.frame` objects or when the `while` loop contains `FALSE` - i.e. `is.character == FALSE`.

Data and code:

```
myListDATA = list(data.frame(c("A", "B", "C")), as.character("Error"), as.character("Error"), data.frame(c("A", "B", "C")), data.frame(c("A", "B", "C")), as.character("Error"))
myListDATA %>% str


fun = function(i){
  i = 1
  while(TRUE){
    if(typeof(myListDATA[[i]]) == "listNOT"){
      next
    }
    if(typeof(myListDATA[[i]]) == "character"){
      print("char", i)
      next
    }
    i = i+1
  }
}

fun(c(1:3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` doesn't iterate, just runs the same thing over and over again. If you want iteration, you need to build that in. I'd suggest something like this, where the `while` loop will cause the `for` loop to keep running, and we leave the iteration to the `for` loop which is good at that sort of thing.

```
while(any(myListDATA == "Error")) {
  ## or maybe you want `while(any(sapply(myListDATA, is.character))`??
  for(i in seq_along(myListDATA)) {
    if(!identical(myListDATA[[i]], "Error")) next
    # or maybe `if(!is.chacater(myListDATA[[i]])) next`
    
    ## code to run on chracter "Error"
    ## for the `while` loop to ever end, these items need to change
    myListDATA[[i]] <- data.frame(x = 1)
  }
}
```

I'm not super clear whether you want to skip items when the the type is `character` (I'd suggest using `is.character`, not `typeof`, unless you have  good reason to prefer `typeof`), or if you want to explicitly check if it is a `character` set to the value `"Error"`. Both options are in this code, one in comments.